# ASP.NET:Integrating many pages to one using jQuery UI dialog

Tags: asp.net, jquery, jquery-ui-dialog

I have a four ASP.NET pages,Page 1.aspx,Page2.aspx,page3.aspx and page4.aspx.Normally the user will come to Page1 and then enter his data in the form elements.On clicking on the Go button Page 2 will come and so on up to page 4.Now i want to Integrate all of these items to A single page using jQuery LightBox/UI dialog modal popup.In my all pages i have server side code to do some Business logic.So I tried to Put the contents of page 2 in a panel and put it in the UI modal dialog and placed in page 1 and invoke the UI dialog from page 1 's button click.But my problem is I am not sure when i click on the button of the panel which is placed in the UI dialog, will trigger the server side code .I had some problems when i tried it earlier

[ASP.NET with jQueryUI: text box value is getting as null in Button click event](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/876660/asp-net-with-jqueryui-text-box-value-is-getting-as-null-in-button-click-event)

Please advice

Thanks in advance

Comment: Anybody there to help me out ?

Answer (score 0):

I got the answer after a long search, jquery's thick box pluggin is ideal.We can use this to show single photo,inline content,another page,contect fetched using ajax etc.. Really cool